# Android Alarm Receiver Not fired on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, service, gps, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have created an application which consists of Service that will send GPS coordinates to the Server. So Currently I am activating the service through Alarm class i.e, if we say 60 seconds , then Alarm class should be fired and start the service and then goes off.

These are all the features working on android 2.3.6 versions. But If I tried to work on Jelly bean alarm receiver and broadcast receiver are not calling.

```
I have registered the receiver in the manifest file like below,

   <receiver android:name="com.receivers.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

And in the Alarm Receiver class like below,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
        //Intent i = new Intent(context, GPSLoggerService.class);
        //i.setAction("com.varma.samples.gpslogger.receivers.KEEP_ALIVE");
        //i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        //context.startService(i);
        //System.out.println("hi::");
        context.startService(new Intent(context,GPSLoggerService.class));
        }
}
```

And finally I have the `GPSLOggerservice` class which sends lat,long to the Server.

So my problem is that, Alarm receiver is not called when time comes so that I am unable to start the services . How to overcome this on higher versions like Jelly Bean and later ? However it is working fine on lower versions like 2.3.6 as i tested earlier.

Comment: for Jelly Bean are you using any HTC device ?

Comment: No I am Using Samsung.

Comment: Ok, do you have any activity in your project ?

Comment: Yes , I have an activity.

Comment: Is it giving NullPointerException on Jelly Bean ?

Comment: No Null Pointer Exception, Actually unable to start the receive through alarm receiver. that means alarm receiver is not triggered. In my logcat it is not showing any error.

Comment: Can you upload BroadcastReceiver,Service and the activity code along with .xml file's code ?

Comment: Above I posted BroadcastCastReciever and xml code

Comment: I know but this small code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the release of Honeycomb, BroadcastReceivers are installed in a stopped state and will not trigger until an application has actually run, i.e. you must have an activity to have run at least once.

Please Look @ [Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) and @ [Background Regression](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)